# Data lost - Client/Server

Tags: java

I'm trying to write simple online status displayer in JAVA for my communicator Client-Server. When someone connects it shows new member online in my JList. Simple. I have a class called "container" which (as the name suggests) contains reference to List Object and a message object. My list is a simple map, where key is an unique ID for each user and String is his nickname. This map is in List Object as a field. Then, I send this serialized object to a client. The problem is that when I have two clients, first who connects to server see only 1 online (himself) and the second one see both (2 online). It is strange becouse for example when I send only a integer with a numer of online members, both clients see "2" - so it's correct and when I try to print numbers of online clients before sending to client (map.size()) i see "2". So before sending is good but after reading is only "1" (for first client). How is that possible?

Server side:

```
private void rewrite() {
    online.clear();
    for(int key : handlerMap.keySet()) {
        online.put(handlerMap.get(key).getId(), handlerMap.get(key).getNickname());              
    }     
}

public void run() {
    try {
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        container = new MsgContainer();
        list = new OnlineList();

        while(!interrupt) {
            rewrite();
            list.setOnlineList(online);
            container.setMessage(message);
            container.setList(list); 
            System.out.println("klucz - "+id+" ----------" 

+container.getList().getOnlineList().size()); //id is an unique id. It shows 2 online `for` 
//1st client and 2 for 2cnd. All ok. But when I send and read on first client's side it `//shows only 1,`
            oos.writeObject(container);
            message = null;
            Thread.sleep(100);
        }
        oos.close();
    } 
    catch(InterruptedException e) { System.out.println(e); }
    catch(IOException e) { System.out.println(e); } 

    threadOnlineList.interrupt();
}
```

Client side:

```
public void run() {
    try {
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        while(!interrupt) {
            if(ois.readObject() != null) {
                MsgContainer container = (MsgContainer) ois.readObject();
                //updateList(container.getList().getOnlineList());
                System.out.println(container.getList().getOnlineList().size()); 
////shows 
//1 for first client and 2 for second one.
            }
            Thread.sleep(100);
        }
        ois.close();
    } 
    catch(IOException e) { System.out.println(e); }
    catch(InterruptedException e) { System.out.println(e); }
    catch(ClassNotFoundException e) { System.out.println(e); }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When the first client connects, you send the list of clients. This includes Client 1. When Client 2 connects, you send the list of clients. This includes Client 1 and Client 2. the first client only sees 1 connection because there only is one. If you want the first client to see both connections, you will need to update all of the clients every time a client connects or disconnects from the server.

Comment: yes I do that. I have a reference to map of objects "ConnectionHandler". Every new client has his own "ConnectionHandler". Then I put this handler into a map of Connection Handlers <Int, ConnectionHandler> where int is an unique id. When someone connects to a server I put a new handler into a map and every ConnectionHandler object has reference to this map and see that someone has connected (thanks to this reference to map).

Comment: Now I see where you're coming from. When you send the map over to each client, it doesn't stay synced up with the server version. It's taking a snapshot of the server version and sending a copy of it.

Comment: Yes, it could be true. Could you tell me how to solve it without destroying my entire program? I worked very hard and it may be for nothing...

Comment: When a new client joins, you need to resend the map to everyone with an active connection. You could try upgrading your code but it probably isn't worth it. Networking gets very complicated (and a bit frustrating) very easily. I recommend doing some more research on networking in general. You should also take a look at [Netty](https://netty.io/). I have never personally used it but I just stumbled upon it and it looks very promising.

Comment: Thank you for your time but I told that every ConnectionHandler has access to this map. Every ConnectionHandler (Client on server side) see who is connected, this map is like a global variable. Look at that: http://wklej.org/id/933826/ if I display "handlers" in ConnectionHandler class I get all members online, their nicknames, id etc. Then I create a simple map with ID and nickname every member (thanks to "handlers" map) - it works, but when I send it's not

Comment: That's not true. Just because two variables have the same name doesn't make them the same variable. What you are looking at are two variables with the same type, same name, but completely different scope. Basically, both of those variables know nothing about each other. If they did, it wouldn't be valid code.

Comment: The solution was simple. oos.reset()